# Image Padding Loaded in TextView

Tags: android, html, image, textview, padding

I made an app that loads images from wordpress blog and display it in a `TextView`. For doing that I used `Html.ImageGetter`. Now the problem is I want to set `padding` for the texts but not for the images. Is there any way that I can set padding for texts but disable padding for Images in the same `TextView`?

P.S: I don't have any `ImageView`. I parse all data from wp rest api as json and load it in a single `TextView` using `HTML.ImageGetter`.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know not, but you could try if setting textAlignment to center/left work for your case.

Otherwise you could use Button instead of TextView, in Buttons u can set padding for text only.